# Is there an easier way to outline individual states in Bing maps than manually drawing the custom polygons?

Tags: charts, bing-maps, bing-api

I'm looking to create a data visualization where the states of the US are shaded different colors based on data.  So, what would be ideal in using a tool like Bing Maps would be to have each state be represented by a custom polygon that I can then shade to the appropriate color.
So, my question is, is there an easy way to select a state and create a custom layer on that state besides trying to create a custom polygon?
I feel like there must be an easier way to do it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you won't find this natively in the Bing map SDK. So the only 2 ways to do this are:

- Adding polygons for each states [(polygon demo here)](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#Shapes8). You could try working from geodata in [that KML file](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=kml%20us%20states&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/us_states.kml&ei=0FDXTpB75YfiBIf9_fwN&usg=AFQjCNEWXuNW1-qcDLlcVBMy2TiySDlWTQ&sig2=w01cszvedz4iKsmuUPUIdg)
- Building your own set of tiles (a.k.a. custom layer) and overlay it on top of the map [this way](http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#TileLayers2)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way now, with Bing Maps SDS (Spatial Data Services).

```
Microsoft.Maps.SpatialDataService.GeoDataAPIManager.getBoundary()
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/spatial-data-services-module-examples/geodata-api/load-single-boundary-geodata-example